# I was confused, what is differences between jboss esp6.1 and jboss as7?

Tags: java, jboss

i am a newbie,today i am tring to use jboss and deploy my application with jboss,i did't use
jboss before ,when i try to download ,i log into the official website,click download Jboss Application Software 7,but it jump to JBOSS eap6.1.final download place,so i download the EAP6.1 instead. after sometinme of probing,i start the  server with standalone mode and upload my app war file with Management Console,but i cann't access my app,my application name is MedicineManage

```
i try with:   http://localhost:8080/medicineManage/login.jsp
```

here is the result

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /medicineManage/login.jsp
```

what's the difference between AS7 and EAP6.1.0

somebody can explain for  me ! thanks a lot

Comment: Just try to fix the issue. looks like page not found on the path. check your web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

AS is the application server and it is an open source.

EAP is the enterprise application platform supported by red hat and red hat is often releasing the patches for this version.

For more detail just go through the web page it has clear difference between application server AS and Enterprise application platform.

http://planet.jboss.org/post/security_community_jboss_as_versus_jboss_eap

Comment: how can i access my deployed app ?

Comment: I dont know how you deployed and all. Need more info on that

Comment: i use Management Console to upload my app

Comment: my app is a war file,should i place any jboss-config information in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Boot time of Jboss as 7 is less than Jboss EAP 6.1 and also memory consumption is less in Jboss as 7.

Find more about Jboss EAP 6.1 from [here](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap.html) and Jboss as 7 from [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas). Follow these links for documentation about [Jboss EAP 6.1](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/) and [Jboss as 7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Documentation).

How ever **JBoss EAP is a product that is officially supported by Red Hat. You get patches, updates, security fixes etc. It is shipped secure.**